# Specifying an alternate name for junit.jar for the ant junit task

Tags: ant, junit

By default [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) jars have the version number in the file name, eg *junit-4.8.2.jar*. [The JUnit Ant Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) only looks for junit.jar. Is it possible to specify a name based on the standard naming convention. I'd like to do so because I want to reference libs in my local [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, JUnit task documentation gives you a few alternatives:

```
Note: You must have junit.jar available. You can do one of:

    Put both junit.jar and ant-junit.jar in ANT_HOME/lib.
    Do not put either in ANT_HOME/lib, and instead include their locations in your CLASSPATH environment variable.
    Add both JARs to your classpath using -lib.
    Specify the locations of both JARs using a <classpath> element in a <taskdef> in the build file.
    Leave ant-junit.jar in its default location in ANT_HOME/lib but include junit.jar in the <classpath> passed to <junit>. (since Ant 1.7)
```

**EDIT**

This is what you need.

```
<junit
   ...
>
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="/path/to/your/custom/junit-4.8.2.jar""/>
    <path refid="your.other.classpath.dependencies" />
  </classpath>
  ...
</junit>
```

Comment: I realize I can specify the path to junit.jar, but none of those options allow me to rename the file to junit-4.8.2.jar.

Comment: Oh I see now. I was being a little dense, but the documentation could be a bit more explicit that the junit jar could be called something other than junit.jar.